# Cross browser vertical centering for text inside a circle

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, webkit

I'm trying to center text inside of a circle, and have done it successfully in webkit browsers but **unsuccessfully** in Firefox. Here is what I have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZqYdb

Here is my markup:

```
<span class="quantity-badge">10</span>
```

Here are my styles:

```
.quantity-badge {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #0896ea;
}
```

I set the display property as `table-cell` so that adding 3 digits causes the badge to remain circular.

If you compare the demo in Chrome vs Firefox, you will notice that the text in Firefox is slightly towards the top of the badge. How can I vertically center the text in all browsers?

**NOTE**: I am using a Mac with the latest version of El Capitan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.quantity-badge {
  display: block; /*Changed this*/
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height:24px; /*Added this*/
  padding:10px; /*Added this*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%; /*Added this*/
  background-color: #0896ea;
}
```

I hope this can begin to help you out. Here is a fork of the code you posted: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKNevV

Comment: `display: block` won't do in this case, since I need the circle to adjust width based on the how much text inside.

Comment: `font-size` is also important there. With a smaller font size, 2 digits looks ok, though still a bit too far to the right. With a larger font size, I find it works with 1 digit, but that 2 digits doesn't look as centered. Also be careful that the element's `box-sizing` is `content-box` and that the `font-weight` is `normal`. In my particular case, those were important. It's still much more vertically centered in more browsers than other things I've tried.

Comment: Sorry, after increasing the font size, I see that in Firefox, the text is still a bit too high. The internet is just broken.

Answer (score 0):

In my versions of Firefox (38.7.0) and Chrome (49.0.2623.87) they look the same.

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEurx.png)

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iqzz.png)

Comment: Well actually, in Chrome the text looks slightly higher. Could you post screenshots of what you're seeing?

Comment: I am using the latest versions of both browsers. Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/k4aNF6M.png
Firefox: http://i.imgur.com/9mvfD6a.png